# Develop application for Linux in C#

Tags: c#

I want to develop application for Linux in C#. The .NET framework is supported only for Windows platform.

Comment: Search for Mono project ;).

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by shA.t in the comments,  The [Mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/)  can be the answer to your need, it's a platform designed to create cross platform .NET applications

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core is now open source.  Here is a quick get started with .NET Core on Ubuntu Linux: [Getting started with .NET on Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu)

Short and sweet.

1. Download the dotnet package:

   ```
   ~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' 
   ~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
   ~$ sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install the package

   ```
   ~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet
   ```